# Monitor single page loading times in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, monitoring, performance-testing, single-page-application

I've got an existing single page web application of which I can't change the code. Some users complain that the application is not performing very well.

I would like to monitor the loading time in this way:

1. Record the time stamp of a click on the page
2. Record the time stamp of when the rendering of the page has been completed, after ajax requests and some other javascript magic has been done
3. Calculate the difference between the two time stamps and post it back to the server.

I can easily do step 1 and 3 with jQuery, however I'm not sure what's the best way to approach step 2?

As this seems to be a quite obvious scenario, is there a standard tool set to perform this kind of monitoring?

Comment: Perhaps you can start with [`Navigation timing Api`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing)

Comment: @Teemu: Expanded a bit, that looks like an answer to me (and a good one). :-)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the solution should also work in IE8.

Comment: You are able to add some "global" jQuery code to the page?

Comment: @smhg I can add additional scripts if they don't interfere with the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

This helps:

```
function onLoad() { 
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;
  console.log("User-perceived page loading time: " + page_load_time);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the solution should also work with IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the global [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) event jQuery offers.

```
var start = +(new Date());
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    var diff = +(new Date()) - start;
    // do logging
});
```

This won't include the code executed after the last AJAX call, but if things happening before the last call contain the expected bottleneck, then this will be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved in following way...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var startTime, endTime, timeDifference;
        function doIt() {
            var startTime = new Date().getTime();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'a.php',
                success: function (resp) {
                    endTime = new Date().getTime();
                    timeDifference = endTime - startTime; //Time Difference is stored in milliseconds
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button style="position: absolute; top:60px" onclick="doIt()">start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't change the current code. For this to work I must add code before and after the current ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, however the following code is working. It start the timer when a user clicks. The `checkHTML` function monitors the changes in the page content.

```
var timeLogging = new Array();
var timeStart;

$(document).click(function() {
    initLogEvent();
});

function initLogEvent() {
    caption = $(".v-captiontext:first").text();
    timeStart = +(new Date());
    timeLogging.push(new Array(0,0));
    timeLogging[timeLogging.length - 1][0] = timeStart;
}

initLogEvent();
// Start a timer to check the changes in html
window.setInterval(checkHtml, 250);
// Start a timer to create the reports
window.setInterval(sendReport, 1000);


var html;
function checkHtml() {
    current = $("body").html();
    if (current != html) {
        html = current;
        var diff = +(new Date()) - timeStart;
        timeLogging[timeLogging.length - 1][1] = diff;
    }
}

function sendReport() {
    if (timeLogging.length > 3) {
        console.log(timeLogging);
        // Do additional stuff with the collected data
        for (i = 0; i <= timeLogging.length; i++) {
            timeLogging.shift();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping all you application's markup in the page, even when it is hidden? If so you are probably choking the browser's memory. I recommend learning to offload your markup in localStorage like Bing and Google pioneers a few years ago. I wrote a blog about it the day I discovered the technique and I have used it ever since.

http://love2dev.com/#!article/Use-Local-Storage-to-Make-Your-Single-Page-Web-Application-Rock